# Efficient loading of directory sorted by modification date

Tags: python, performance, operating-system

I am reading a directory with Python, containing *many* files, most of which are old.
However, I am only interested in the files generated in the past 24h.

Running something like

```
for filename in os.listdir(dir_path):
    if now - timedelta(hours=24) <= os.path.getmtime(filename) <= now:
        do_something()
```

takes very long since the entire `dir_path` is scanned.

Is there a quicker possibility to load `dir_path` with the files sorted by modification date?

Comment: Can you qualify "takes very long"? Listing the directory and acquiring the modification time for each file should not be slow. Is the directory on some kind of network storage? Are you sure that it's not *do_something()* that's taking the bulk of the time?

Comment: Please provide the OS of the target platform, the kind of storage device (SSD/HDD) and its access type (network/USB/PCI) as well as the number of files in the directory. This is critical for *reproducibility*.

Comment: Large numbers of files in a directory can itself be a performance problem at the operating system level, and you can't do anything about that in application code that relies on the OS to get files. I don't know if that's the case here, but if it is, consider using date-related subfolders. However I generally file them under folders by creation time. That won't help with modified time. You might need your own metadata for that.

Answer (score 0):

Although tested on a fairly small directory, this code demonstrates how (on a regular filesystem) parsing of the directory and checking st_mtime should be fast.

```
from pathlib import Path
from datetime import datetime
from time import perf_counter

def do_something(_):
    pass

start = perf_counter()
count = 0

for file in Path("/Users/CtrlZ").iterdir():
    count += 1
    mtime = datetime.fromtimestamp(file.stat().st_mtime)
    if (datetime.now() - mtime).total_seconds() > 24 * 60 * 60:
        do_something(file)

duration = perf_counter() - start

print(f"Total files = {count} Duration = {duration:.4f}s")
```

**Output:**

```
Total files = 421 Duration = 0.0025s
```